# What's the running principle of React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, javascriptcore

For example, generally the app runs on the Dalvik JVM in Android. However, when we use react native to develop our app, there is a JS bundle which can not run on JVM. The react native website says that the JS code is running on JavaScriptCore on devices. Does that mean in android, the JavaScriptCore runs JS code and JVM runs .class code simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, an embedded copy of JavaScriptCore runs JS and of course ART or Dalvik runs Java bytecode. React Native also includes JNI libraries that run natively on ARM.

On iOS it is simpler. The OS's copy of JavaScriptCore runs JS and Objective-C runs natively on ARM.